# Change wearablelistView item heigth

Tags: wear-os

I am facing problem with wearable listview,I have more than 3 textview to show in wearable listview item,but it from bottom due to har coded heigth of list item.Is there any way to change the height of item.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change that if you user WearableListView. You can write your own RecyclerView extension to do as you wish.